# how to get all files in a directory in ipad using objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, nsfilemanager

i need to get all files in a directory, including all sub directories and all files in each subdirectory. in objective C, i have try to use this method 
`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:nil]`

but it just give me an array of contents file in directory filePath, i cant get all files in the sub directory, can somebody help me??

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
- (void)scanPath:(NSString *) sPath {

    BOOL isDir;

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sPath isDirectory:&isDir];

    if(isDir)
    {
        NSArray *contentOfDirectory=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sPath error:NULL];

        int contentcount = [contentOfDirectory count];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<contentcount;i++)
        {
            NSString *fileName = [contentOfDirectory objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *path = [sPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",@"/",fileName];


            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path])
            {   
                NSLog(path);
                [self scanPath:path];
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sPath];
        NSLog(msg);
    }
}
```

you can call this function which will log all the files in the directory, hope this will help.

Comment: @Risma this is the type of recursive solution I was referring to in the chat room.

Comment: @Risma Please make sure your thanks goes to the right person :)

Comment: @rajesh.adhi, i wanna thank you for both of them, Chris L & arun.s

thank you for you too rajesh :)

Comment: How to avoid hidden files??

Answer (score 5):

You want to use enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:error: instead.  It does a deep enumeration by default:

```
NSURL *myDirectoryURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Assets" withExtension:@""];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtURL:myDirectoryURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray array] options:0 errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    // handle error
    return NO;
}];

NSString *fileOrDirectory = nil;
while ((fileOrDirectory = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])) {
    // use file or directory
}
```

The options argument lets you specify deep or shallow enumeration.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: is it can give me all the files in each directories?

Comment: sorry -- should have been enumeratorAtURL -- this works, tested

Comment: That's one awful looking assignment line.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII thanks, I try :).  I'm not sure why apple puts the error handling in a block -- I suppose you could create the error handling block above and pass it in.